# adal.js with popup not working on edge / internet explorer

Tags: adal, adal.js

I have an angularJS SPA app working with ui.router and the below code is working fine on Chrome and Firefox. On Edge and Internet Explorer, the login popup shows up, I enter my credentials, but then nothing happens.

```
class LoginController {
    constructor($rootScope, $state, adalService) {
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.adalService = adalService;
        this.$rootScope.$on('adal:loginSuccess', function (event, token) {
            console.log('loggedin');
            console.log('token:' + token);
            $state.go('loggedin');
        });
    }

    $onInit()  {
        this.adalService.login();
    }


}
LoginController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', 'adalAuthenticationService'];
export default LoginController;
```

Any ideas on why this is happening ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the script, you were using the `class` keywords which is introduced in **ECMAScript 2015**. And based on ECMAScript [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), the IE 11 doesn't support it.

You may convert the script to the old stand if you want to support more of browser. More detail, you can refer the above link.

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT . 
I'm counting on webpack with babel to handle that.
Anyway, I've settled a "standard" Project, and in IE, the popup shows but then it doesn't close and app continues there. In Edge I can see it for 1 second and then it disapears... you can check it here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlBevQQ5u1azkIRBxZxlfvWLPvpJ5w

Thanks

Comment: Also, I would prefer not to have a popup, but then I can't seem to catch the adal:loginSuccess event...

Comment: After the further investigation, it seems that the IE 11 doesn't support the **CustomEvent** which causes a exception for this issue. And in the Edge, the `_openPopup` function in **adal.js** returns `null` instead of the window object. To use the adal library successfully, I suggest that you use the Chrome browser.

Comment: And based on my understanding, the pop-up window is recommend instead of page redirection. If we use the page redirection for Azure AD login, there is a know issue about the ui-route to switch the state(refer [this issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/530)).

Comment: I can live with the popup but the browser restriction is really awkward.... is there any workaround for Microsoft browsers?

Comment: To improve the browser compatibility for this library, I suggest that you reopen a new issue form this library in [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues).